# `polyglot_original_require': no such file to load -- eventmachine (MissingSourceFile)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have cloned the rails project into my local machine. Then I have installed all needed gems using `bundle install` command. But when I try to start server, I get error:

```
`polyglot_original_require': no such file to load -- eventmachine (MissingSourceFile)
```

When I run `gem list` I can find there `eventmachine` gem. So what is wrong? 
Here is full stack-trace:

```
/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p371/gems/polyglot-0.3.3/lib/polyglot.rb:63:in `polyglot_original_require': no such file to load -- eventmachine (MissingSourceFile)
from /home/oleksandr/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p371/gems/polyglot-0.3.3/lib/polyglot.rb:63:in `require'
from /home/oleksandr/dev/salamstein/vendor/rails/activesupport/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:182:in `require'
from /home/oleksandr/dev/salamstein/vendor/rails/activesupport/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:547:in `new_constants_in'
from /home/oleksandr/dev/salamstein/vendor/rails/activesupport/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:182:in `require'
from /home/oleksandr/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p371/gems/thin-2.0.0.pre/lib/thin/server.rb:1
from /home/oleksandr/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p371/gems/polyglot-0.3.3/lib/polyglot.rb:63:in `polyglot_original_require'
from /home/oleksandr/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p371/gems/polyglot-0.3.3/lib/polyglot.rb:63:in `require'
from /home/oleksandr/dev/salamstein/vendor/rails/activesupport/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:182:in `require'
from /home/oleksandr/dev/salamstein/vendor/rails/activesupport/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:547:in `new_constants_in'
from /home/oleksandr/dev/salamstein/vendor/rails/activesupport/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:182:in `require'
from /home/oleksandr/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p371/gems/thin-2.0.0.pre/lib/thin.rb:3
from /home/oleksandr/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p371@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `require'
from /home/oleksandr/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p371@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `require'
from /home/oleksandr/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p371@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:70:in `each'
from /home/oleksandr/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p371@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:70:in `require'
from /home/oleksandr/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p371@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:59:in `each'
from /home/oleksandr/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p371@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:59:in `require'
from /home/oleksandr/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p371@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler.rb:132:in `require'
from /home/oleksandr/dev/salamstein/config/boot.rb:122:in `load_gems'
from /home/oleksandr/dev/salamstein/config/../vendor/rails/railties/lib/initializer.rb:164:in `process'
from /home/oleksandr/dev/salamstein/config/../vendor/rails/railties/lib/initializer.rb:113:in `send'
from /home/oleksandr/dev/salamstein/config/../vendor/rails/railties/lib/initializer.rb:113:in `run'
from /home/oleksandr/dev/salamstein/config/environment.rb:45
from /home/oleksandr/dev/salamstein/vendor/rails/activesupport/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:182:in `require'
from /home/oleksandr/dev/salamstein/vendor/rails/activesupport/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:182:in `require'
from /home/oleksandr/dev/salamstein/vendor/rails/activesupport/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:547:in `new_constants_in'
from /home/oleksandr/dev/salamstein/vendor/rails/activesupport/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:182:in `require'
from /home/oleksandr/dev/salamstein/vendor/rails/railties/lib/commands/server.rb:84
from script/server:3:in `require'
from script/server:3
```

Thank you.

Comment: Check whether Polygot gem is successfully installed and its dependency version.

Comment: can you put the output of `gem install polyglot`